# git Include a file but have its changes untracked

Tags: git, svn

I'd like to include a source file (have it delivered when someone clones a repository) in my repository but have changes to it ignored by default.

`git update-index --assume-unchanged ...` doesn't work because it only applies to the local index.  I want all users to have the file in question ignored by default.

`.gitignore` doesn't work because if I track a file via `git add -f ..`, then changes to it are tracked.

I'm trying to achieve what would happen if I `svn add` ed the file then `svn:ignore`ed it.

**EDIT:**

*It looks like this just isn't possible in Git and I changed the source file organization and build that relied on this old Subversion behavior.*

Examples:

```
$ git clone git@git:gsmith/sandbox.git
snip...
$ cd sandbox/
$ ls -a
.  ..  .git  .gitignore  gitignored  tracked
$ cat .gitignore 
gitignored

$ echo foo >> gitignored 
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   gitignored
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I would like this file to be ignored.

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD
HEAD is now at 34b1f3d initial setup
$ git rm gitignored
rm 'gitignored'
$ git commit -m "test"
[master cd8199d] test
 1 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 gitignored
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
$ ls -a
.  ..  .git  .gitignore  tracked

$ echo foo >> gitignored
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Now it is ignored.  However, someone who clones the repository will not get the contents of `gitignored`.

Comment: There is no `.svnignore`, only svn:ignore property

Comment: @manojlds, thanks, I've corrected the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the file to your repo specific `.gitignore`.
2. If it's already tracked (may be your case), just do `git rm --cached myfile`.

Hope it's what you want. If not, you may take a look at [this](http://help.github.com/ignore-files/).

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase your title: you want to track a file, but have changes to it untracked. That's as much of a contradiction as it sounds like. Presumably you have some file which gets changed in local ways that aren't meaningful to other users of the repository, but also contains content that everyone needs. The answer, of course, is not to do that. There are two primary options:

- Split the file. One part is the "local" one, which doesn't need to be tracked, and the other part is the core/shared one, containing the things everyone needs, and won't normally modify. You should create the empty/template local file automatically, at build/deploy/runtime as appropriate.
- Deploy the file as a template, and then for use, make a copy of it. You'd do the copy automatically, at build/deploy/runtime as appropriate.

Either way, the question is not "how do I tell Git not to track this file I just told it to track?" but "why am I trying to both track and not track the same content?"

Comment: The problem is that 'track' in git means two things. 1) keep a copy of this file in the repository 2) watch for changes to this file when I commit to the repository. The question involves keeping 1) while removing 2). It's not a contradiction, it's just not a distinction git makes.

Comment: @WaylonFlinn It's a contradiction in the context of Git, which is what the question is about. Keeping a copy while not watching for changes leads to a lot of complications, and Git avoids introducing that, because it's possible (and often in fact much better) to do something like the two options I suggested.